# Group same values from data d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some data that I want to put into a select menu.

Problem is, there are multiple instances of the same values in the data. For example there are multiple instances of `"FirstName": "John"`.

How do I group all of the same values into the select menu rather than having a select menu that has every value from the data?

Comment: Use [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest).

Comment: Thanks, works nicely.